# Printing in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I have created a random image in my windows 8 app. I am willing to print the image using a printer but could not get any idea.

Can anybody help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sample in MSDN Code Gallery:http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6